# Rewrite a generator matrix $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, coding-theory

Given is the following generator matrix which represents a linear code $C \subseteq \mathbb F_2^8$:

$$G=\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\                                              
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\                                              
\end{array}\right)$$

I have to compute the check matrix $H$ which is defined as $H=[-P^T | I_{n-k}]$, this should be no problem, but since $G$ is not in the form $G=[I_k | P]$ which [is required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix) for $H$ i do not know how to do that.

Is it possible to somewhat rewrite $G$ such that $G$ contains $I_3$ without losing any information?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not reduce $G$ to standard form - a couple of row operations should suffice.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you very much. "Reducing to standard form" was the term i wasn't familiar with (https://www.di-mgt.com.au/cgi-bin/matrix_stdform.cgi). This solves my problem!